# Edit Data Connection

Tags: excel, vba

First post, hello to everyone.

I am looking for code for a button when pressed will prompt the user to change the data connection source file.  The following code works to the point of requesting the user to pick a new source file but none of the connections then update with the new filepath, any ideas?  Thanks in advance

```
Sub xlTest()

Dim i As Long
Dim cnt As Long
Dim cn

cnt = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count

'Choose a File
strPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Choose a file", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

If strPath = False Then
    MsgBox "No file selected. Exiting now.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
'Change Connection source filepath for each connection
For i = cnt To 1 Step -1
     Set cn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(i)
     cn.OLEDBConnection.SourceDataFile = strPath
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why are you using the For Next statement, since it looks like you're opening only one file per execution. But I think you can replace the code inside it for `ActiveWorkbook.Connections.AddFromFile (strPath)`, it will prompt you to a dialog to choose a sheet inside to connect, also you don't need to declare your 'cn' variable.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the info.  All the queries come from the same source file albeit different tables.  Do I have to individually update?  When I update manually all I do is change data connection once and all the tables update to this new sheet as the tables have the same reference across all potential connection files.  Thanks

Comment: Your connections have the sheet in the command part, just like "sheet1$", "sheet2$", if they're already set to connect to the prompt'd workbook, and have a command set to a valid sheet in the said workbook, you just need to refresh. If you want to refresh automatically when the user choose a file, you can use <code>For each c in thisworkbook.connections c.refresh next c</code>